# Repeating fieldset is removed when validation fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, asp.net-core-mvc, knockout-mvc

I'm building an app with asp.net MVC Core. I use Knockout to allow user to add/remove `fieldset` in the application form dynamically. The page will render a partial view of "successful page" if the form is successfully submitted.

However, I don't know why the entire  `fieldset` are removed if there's any field fails the validation. Here are the screenshots:

[image: before validation] **---->** [image: after validation]

The script that I use in the form:

```
@section Scripts 
{
  <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/knockout/dist/knockout.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/knockout.namepathbinding.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function ViewModel() {

        var createReferee = function () {
            return {
                refereeName: ko.observable(),
                refereePhone: ko.observable(),
                refereeEmail: ko.observable(),
                refereePosition: ko.observable(),
                refereeCompanyName: ko.observable()
            };
        };

        var addReferee = function() {
            referees.push(createReferee());
        };

        var removeReferee = function() {
            referees.pop();
        };

        var referees = ko.observableArray([createReferee()]);

        return {
            referees: referees,
            addReferee: addReferee,
            removeReferee: removeReferee
        };
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var viewModel = ViewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    });

    $(document).on('submit', '#applyForm', function () {
        var $form = $(this);
        $.post('', $form.serialize())
            .done(function (response) {
                $form.replaceWith(response);
            })
        return false;
    });
  </script>
}
```

Comment: Since bindings are applied to the form you cannot just replace the form element because all bindings of that form will be lost. Honestly I don't see a reason to use Knockout here.

Comment: @f_martinez What is the easiest way for making dynamic `fieldset`?

Comment: Actually there are two ways. The first way is to make your request to return JSON-data and reinitilize viewModel with that data if validation fails (this way uses Knockout). The second way is to make buttons _Add_ and _Remove_ to append/remove cloned node of the fieldset with plain JS or jQuery (I'm proposing this way with asertion that response already contains fieldsets added by user).